# CSS class display

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I am having a CSS class with the following code. I am trying to put a `DIV` at a distance of 140px from the top of webpage and to put it in the middle (equal distance from left and right). It is displaying correctly in Firefox and Google Chrome but not displaying correctly in Internet Explorer 8. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this code? Also can anyone give me some link with browser compatibility guide?

```
div.main
{
    padding: 0px;
    width: 980px;
    /*height:1350px;*/
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*helps in getting the DIV to be in middle i.e. equal distance from left and right*/
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin-top:140px;
}
```

Comment: start with merging margins - `margin: 140px auto 0 auto;`, and, please, tell what version of IE gives you troubles ?

Comment: With merging also it is not displaying properly. IE8.

Comment: [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E9gWd/1/) works fine in IE8, is this *all* of the CSS that's styling the element? Are you *sure*? Can you define what "not displaying correctly" means? Is it the centering or the top margin or what?

Comment: @Wesley: Yes this is the only one which is styling the element. I got the problem partially corrected by using the answer by Webars. But page is displaying on the left side (not in the middle).

Comment: And the demo I posted with your code is also "not working"? I have a genuine IE8 install and it looks fine to me. Can you produce a demo that shows the incorrect rendering?

Comment: @Wesley: Not sure why demo looks okay. In JSFIDDLE it looks okay. I will try to do some testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin-top:140px;` is "the problem". To reach your aim use:

- padding-top instead of margin-top;
- if you cann't - make a wrapper div and apply padding-top to it;
- or apply `position: relative/absolute; top: 140px;` to the div. It is suitable
  sometimes.

Comment: `margin-top` is not "the problem" - it should work fine in IE8. Padding is not something you can just swap with margin, and there is no reason to, margins will work fine in IE.

Comment: @Webars: Thanks! I got the problem partially corrected by using the answer. But page is displaying on the left side (not in the middle). What should I do to correct it?

Comment: width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; - these styles center the page. If you have no margins except them - it should work. If not - make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Wesley Murch if you have no background - padding and margin will give the same result. As for me, I use padding everywhere I can, because it gives guaranteed result in all browsers, including IE6 and IE7.

Comment: I hear ya, I tend to use unfloated wrapper divs with margin to "pad" content. I feel like IE6/7 will still be haunting us for some time to come, but there are no top/bottom margin bugs in any IE version that I am aware of.

Comment: @Webars: It is working in Jsfiddle. But not in IE. Please help! http://jsfiddle.net/rwTgc/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rwTgc/9/ Tested in IE6-8. Maybe your window width is smaller than 980px?

Comment: @Webars: Got the problem! It was not working because there was no DOCTYPE, <meta> tag etc. in my HTML page. Now it is working fine. Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I find [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) most helpful for browser compatibility info, plus it has some other great info.

The problem, however, depends on more than just the CSS.  In order to answer your question, we'll need to see some HTML and the rest of the CSS you've got.  And a description of what's incorrect with IE's rendering.  Without seeing that, my first suggestion is to make sure you're using a strict DOCTYPE.

Note that centering the DIV will only center it in the containing block (probably BODY), which, wichout an explicit width, will only be as wide as the content and not the full width of the window.